# How to copy a directory from the source to resulting jar in maven

Tags: java, maven, vaadin

I need to copy a directory from my source to the root of the jar which is generated by maven build.

(The purpose of this is, to generate a reusable `vaadin` theme jar. As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34652435/1015678) answer, I need to copy the `VAADIN` directory from source to the root of the jar)

Can someone point me a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to do a very simple thing. I placed the `VAADIN` directory inside `src\main\resources` and it automatically got copied into the root of the resulting jar when `install` target is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

[Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/)

Using this you can specify fileSets and dependency sets. For example

```
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${basedir}/lib</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>*.jar</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
 </fileSets>
```

Comment: Assembly plugin creates another jar in addition to the main jar. I need to add the directory to the original jar

Comment: U can remove the existing jar plugin. Add only assembly plugin

Comment: I haven't added jar plugin to pom, but still it generates the jar. Also, the name of the jar created by assembly plugin is different, so any artifacts which depends on this artifact will not refer to the jar created by assembly plugin

Comment: As u may know artifacts name can be changed in assembly plugin as per ur requirements.